# Room How to fetch on 3 tables with Foreign Keys

Tags: kotlin, foreign-keys, android-room, one-to-one

I have a table named User. This table has two foreign keys Account and Shop (both 1..1 relationship).
So I've created a data class called UserAndAccount and another called UserAndShop.

How can I now fetch all this data (would be equal to UserAndAccountAndShop) ?

User.kt

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "User"
)
data class User(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    @SerializedName("unique_id")
    var uniqueID: String,

    @SerializedName("email")
    var email: String = "",

    @SerializedName("username")
    var username: String = ""
)
```

Account.kt

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "Account"
)
data class Account(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @SerializedName("account_id")
    var accountID: Int,

    @SerializedName("user_id")
    var userOwnerID: String = "",

    @SerializedName("token")
    var token: String = ""
)
```

Shop.kt

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "Shop"
)
data class Shop(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @SerializedName("shop_id")
    var shopID: Int,

    @SerializedName("shop_owner_id")
    var shopOwnerID: String,

    @SerializedName("shop_name")
    var shopName: String = ""
)
```

UserAndAccount.kt

```
data class UserAndAccount(
    @Embedded val user: User,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "uniqueID",
        entityColumn = "userOwnerID"
    )
    val account: Account
)
```

UserAndShop.kt

```
data class UserAndShop(
    @Embedded val user: User,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "uniqueID",
        entityColumn = "shopOwnerID"
    )
    val shop: Shop
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone looking for an answer:

You can add multiples @Relation into a data class.
So I've created this data class:

UserAndAccountAndShop.kt

```
data class UserAndAccountAndShop(
    @Embedded val user: User,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "uniqueID",
        entityColumn = "accountOwnerID"
    )
    val account: Account,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "uniqueID",
        entityColumn = "shopOwnerID"
    )
    val shop: Shop
)
```

And that's it!